# How do I force LF in a Windows git sandbox for a specific file?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, git, whitespace

One of my project's third party build steps requires LF line endings in an XML configuration file, regardless of whether the build occurs on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Our git sandboxes use CRLF on Windows, and LF on Mac/Linux for convenience, and our repository is LF. I need **just this one file** to be LF everywhere.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably use a [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file to set the line endings for that one file:

```
yourfilename.txt text eol=lf
```